# unexpected output in postman

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

There is no error, just I not getting the output which i am expecting in postman.

such as not showing the product data, payment_intent: null etc.

Could you please help me to fix this?

Here is the output which i am getting

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "session": {
        "id": "cs_test_a1mZ6W9dAO1n7IgpBkvZFJR3Uoe0TTAv3BV9U76b9JVpogcbOyImkaAvU2",
        "object": "checkout.session",
        "after_expiration": null,
        "allow_promotion_codes": null,
        "amount_subtotal": 99700,
        "amount_total": 99700,
        "automatic_tax": {
            "enabled": false,
            "status": null
        },
        "billing_address_collection": null,
        "cancel_url": "http://127.0.0.1:3000/tour/the-mountain-biker",
        "client_reference_id": "64482b81fc72db55d5ab256c",
        "consent": null,
        "consent_collection": null,
        "created": 1682624190,
        "currency": "usd",
        "currency_conversion": null,
        "custom_fields": [],
        "custom_text": {
            "shipping_address": null,
            "submit": null
        },
        "customer": null,
        "customer_creation": "if_required",
        "customer_details": {
            "address": null,
            "email": "leo@example.com",
            "name": null,
            "phone": null,
            "tax_exempt": "none",
            "tax_ids": null
        },
        "customer_email": "leo@example.com",
        "expires_at": 1682710590,
        "invoice": null,
        "invoice_creation": {
            "enabled": false,
            "invoice_data": {
                "account_tax_ids": null,
                "custom_fields": null,
                "description": null,
                "footer": null,
                "metadata": {},
                "rendering_options": null
            }
        },
        "livemode": false,
        "locale": null,
        "metadata": {},
        "mode": "payment",
        "payment_intent": null,
        "payment_link": null,
        "payment_method_collection": "always",
        "payment_method_options": {},
        "payment_method_types": [
            "card"
        ],
        "payment_status": "unpaid",
        "phone_number_collection": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "recovered_from": null,
        "setup_intent": null,
        "shipping_address_collection": null,
        "shipping_cost": null,
        "shipping_details": null,
        "shipping_options": [],
        "status": "open",
        "submit_type": null,
        "subscription": null,
        "success_url": "http://127.0.0.1:3000/",
        "total_details": {
            "amount_discount": 0,
            "amount_shipping": 0,
            "amount_tax": 0
        },
        "url": "https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a1mZ6W9dAO1n7IgpBkvZFJR3Uoe0TTAv3BV9U76b9JVpogcbOyImkaAvU2#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blpxYHZxWjA0SzRTa1FWQkNTSE9%2FN3BEXFF3RlJvVXJnVn02bV0yQEh8ZEJrVW01bHFPYHxqUzxtbjFBRkpdc2phMU9oUTA8NVFUU19BQXE0XGRHXHBcMTBGQH1PYUI2NTVmf1xTd0FhSicpJ2N3amhWYHdzYHcnP3F3cGApJ2lkfGpwcVF8dWAnPyd2bGtiaWBabHFgaCcpJ2BrZGdpYFVpZGZgbWppYWB3dic%2FcXdwYHgl"
    }
}
```

**Here is my code, BTW using stripe@7**

```
    const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
    const Tour = require('./../models/tourModel');
    const catchAsync = require('./../utils/catchAsync');
    const factory = require('./handlerFactory');
    const AppError = require('./../utils/appError');
    
    exports.getCheckoutSession = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
      //1) Get the currently booked tour
      const tour = await Tour.findById(req.params.tourId);
      //2) Create checkout session
      console.log(tour);
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        success_url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/`,
        cancel_url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/tour/${tour.slug}`,
        customer_email: req.user.email,
        client_reference_id: req.params.tourId,
    
        line_items: [
          {
            quantity: 1,
            price_data: {
              currency: 'usd',
              unit_amount: tour.price * 100,
              product_data: {
                name: `${tour.name} Tour`,
                description: tour.summary,
                images: [`https://www.natours.dev/img/tours/${tour.imageCover}`],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
    
        // metadata: {
        //   name: `${tour.name} Tour`,
        //   description: tour.summary,
        //   image: `https://www.natours.dev/img/tours/${tour.imageCover}`,
        // },
    
        mode: 'payment',
      });
    
      //3) Create session as response
      res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
    session,
  });
});
```

I am expecting proper output in below fields in postman.

as data is not getting reflected in  **product_data**, **payment_intent: null**,  fields

Answer (score 1):

Why are you expecting the Payment Intent to exist when you create the Checkout Session?  The Checkout Session creates the Payment Intent when the Customer uses the Payment Page to complete the Payment.  This property will have the ID of the Payment Intent *after* it is paid successfully.

As for the product data, it is mentioned in the [API Reference Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items) that this isn't included by default.  It is expandable though.  This means you can pass in `line_items` in the [expand parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/expand) when you create the Checkout Session to get the full `line_items` data in the response.